# how to completeWakefulIntent on other function?

Tags: android

I want to use `completeWakefulIntent` to finish `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, for general case, we can ...

```
public class service_main extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
          receiver_alarm.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

but for my case, I start a listener on `onHandleIntent` like this:

```
public class service_main extends IntentService {

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(sensor_event_listener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }


    private SensorEventListener sensor_event_listener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                //some code

                //unregisterListener
                sensorManager.unregisterListener(sensor_event_listener);

                //here I want to use completeWakefulIntent
                receiver_alarm.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want finish processing the data from sensor then use `completeWakefulIntent`, but I got an error on `receiver_alarm.completeWakefulIntent(intent);` which is `cannot resolve symbol 'intent'`, i know the intent not transfer to this listener, but I cannot know how to fix this, I'm new one for android, could some one give me some suggestion, thank you.

Comment: `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` is deprecated. But, you could save the `intent` parameter to `onHandleIntent()` in a field on your service, then reference that field later on.

Comment: thank you for give me tips, I use `on_handle_intent = intent;` to save intent, and `receiver_alarm.completeWakefulIntent(on_handle_intent);` to use it, it's working, thanks again.